# Getting information behind a javascript button in html code

Tags: javascript, html-parsing

I am trying to parse an html file present on the web that has some information in two tabs, say `Tab X` and `Tab Y`. When the page loads, the HTML source shows contents of `Tab X` by default. Contents in `Tab Y` can be accessed by clicking on it. How can I, using a program,  get the contents of `Tab Y`, assuming that I am downloading the html files with `wget`? The contents of `Tab Y` are loaded with some `javascript` code `__do_postBack()` type functions.

P.S: I am new to this. Please let me know in case more information is required.

Comment: Just to clarify for everyone. You want to download some information from a website. This website is using tabs (and perhaps Ajax) with the content inside?

Comment: I dont think the content is `Ajax`(I am not sure). The `__do_postBack()` functions I mentioned are invoked from within html elements like so: `href=javascript:__do_postBack('lnk_gainers')...`

Answer (score 1):

The `__do_postBack()` function most likely is an ASP.NET postback function. It sends the new POST request to the server. So you need to send new POST request with wget with the same values, as they in are the html form fields.

Comment: thanks for the reply! the `__do_postback()` function is most likely `javascript` code. It is invoked like so: `href=javascript:__do_postBack('lnk_gainers')...`. I tried to invoke `wget` with the POST option by setting `post-data 'lnk_gainers'` but that does not help. Can you give me an example of how to use `wget` with the `POST` option?

Comment: Install Firefox, install Firebug, open the Firebug panel and watch the Console-window. Are there any requests sent when the link is clicked? Javascript can use Ajax, or ASP.NET to load external information. So if you download this file, you will not acquire the information you are looking for, because it's not loaded yet.

Comment: I installed Firebug, but the console window shows nothing when I click on the tab. Are there any settings I need to change? Also, why dont you make your comment into an answer? It would be easier to keep the discussion relevant to the answer..